# Checking for duplicates in table

Tags: sql, t-sql

I have two tables (contacts and emailaddresses) and I want to see if there are any duplicates, either first + last name OR email address, but I'm not sure if this is going to get me what I want?

```js
DECLARE @lClientId int;
SET @lClientId = @ClientId;

WITH Dups
AS (
  SELECT C.ClientId
      ,C.FirstName
      ,C.LastName
      ,EA.Email
      ,C.ContactId
      ,C.IsDeleted
  FROM   Contacts C
   LEFT JOIN EmailAddresses EA
    ON EA.ParentId = C.ContactId
  WHERE C.ClientId = @ClientId 
 )
SELECT Dups1.ContactId
FROM Dups
 INNER JOIN Dups Dups1
  ON Dups1.ClientId = Dups.ClientId
  AND Dups1.FirstName = Dups.FirstName
  AND Dups1.LastName = Dups.LastName
  OR Dups1.Email = Dups.Email
WHERE Dups.IsDeleted = 0
```

Answer (score 1):

For a test data like this

```
Firstname  lastname   email
 a          a1        smp
 a          a1        bmp
 c           d        dmp
 c          e         dmp
```

output of dups will be..,you can change order by to get data in deterministic way

```
 a a1 smp
  c e dmp

DECLARE @lClientId int;
SET @lClientId = @ClientId;

WITH Dups
AS (
        SELECT C.ClientId
               ,C.FirstName
               ,C.LastName
               ,EA.Email
               ,C.ContactId
               ,C.IsDeleted
                Row_number() over (partition by firstname,lastname order by(select null)) as fnamerownum,
 Row_number() over (partition by email order by(select null)) as emailrownum
        FROM   Contacts C
            LEFT JOIN EmailAddresses EA
                ON EA.ParentId = C.ContactId
        WHERE C.ClientId = @ClientId
)
select * from dups
where fnamerownum>1 or emailrownum>1
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want the list of duplicated first + last name OR email

you can

```
SELECT    C.FirstName
        , C.LastName
        , EA.Email
        , count(*)
    FROM   Contacts C
        LEFT JOIN EmailAddresses EA
            ON EA.ParentId = C.ContactId
group by   C.FirstName
         , C.LastName
         , EA.Email
having count(*) > 1
```

Comment: this doesn't find dups that are a duplicate of the first and last name together does it?